# How Can I Enable Root SSH Access in An Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, lamp

This issue has been bugging me for the past several days.

I've been working on setting up a LAMP Server on Amazon EC2. The main issue is that I'm writing an application for a client that requires a lot of high-end processing, and Amazon EC2 seemed like a good choice.

Initially I started off with a basic AMI which really didn't have anything. I tried using root access to log into SSH (using WinSCP) and I was told to use ec2-user.

I tried using ec2-user, and I was able to log in. However, I still didn't have root access and couldn't install apache. I did some reason and I found out about the "sudo" command, and pretty much every article I read on this issue said to either use root access, or log into ec2-user and user sudo.

I have since tried again with a different AMI where LAMP was already installed. I was able to get it working, set up a database and start running a website off of it. However, I still needed to install some extensions. Namely, an API I'm trying to use for this application requires SOAP to be installed.

Here's my dilemma:

```
/$ whereis soap
soap:
/$ whereis yum
yum: /usr/bin/yum /etc/yum /etc/yum.conf /usr/share/man/man8/yum.8.gz
/$ yum install php-soap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
You need to be root to perform this command.
/$ sudo yum install php-soap
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Command 'sudo yum install php-soap' failed with return code 1 and error message sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

I can't use yum because I don't have root access, and whenever I log into root it either tells me to use ec2-user or provide a password I don't have. The other alternative was to use sudo to make ec2-user act like root, but I always get the error 'sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo.' I've ran that error message online and that it seems I need to add a user to sudoers... which I can't do without root access.

This exact same issue plagued me on two separate AMI's. On the first I just received a message saying I had to log in as ec2-user (and I must have a tty to run sudo), while the second (with LAMP installed) required me to enter a password for root, and for user I got the same sudo error.

Here are the id's of the AMI's I used:

```
ami-8c1fece5
ami-6ae81503
```

I also tried a third AMI later that also had LAMP installed... I couldn't even get into that one at all.

I did download my SSH key and used PuttyGen to convert it to a ppk file. I can log in successfully as ec2-user, but I cannot gain root access anywhere.

I have been looking around quite a bit for help on this, but every article I've read assumes that the user either has root access available or has sudo available on ec2-user. I don't have either. Is it just that I need a new image?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: really, this is not a programming issue or related to stackoverflow.com ... should be moved over to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ -- Dan Grossman answered your question however...

Comment: I figured it was related to programming so it would count...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a real SSH client like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), not WinSCP, a file transfer client. All your problems will disappear.

Comment: Thanks... I'm kinda new to command-line prompts and SSH, so I just assumed that WinSCP's would work fine... I got it working now.

Comment: +1 the only thing made it work for me is running sudo from PuTTY and not WinSCP - Thanks a million, made my day :)

Comment: this... actually doesn't answer the "*How Can I Enable Root SSH Access in An Amazon EC2 Instance?*" question...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's because his real question was "how do I get past this error `you must have a tty to run sudo`". The answer to the more general, but not relevant to the asker, question posed in the title, appears below mine. It's been answered here for 5 years, so I'm not sure why you felt the need to post that comment now.

Comment: Oh.. I wasn't fulfilling a need, just stating my understanding on what I was seeing. No offense meant.

Comment: This is not the answer

Answer (score 78):

I just tried

```
$ sudo su
```

on one of your amis and voila! I am root...

Have fun!

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-244-146-238 ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-10-244-146-238 ec2-user]#
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've done this before and it still didn't work. The problem was the program I was trying to use (I just thought that WinSCP's command prompt would work the same as anything else, but apparently not...)

Comment: we can set a password to root like this and how can enable root user ? Default it is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

For Debian or Ubuntu EC2:

1. Set root password via putty:

   ```
   sudo passwd root
   ```
2. Log in to putty as root

   ```
   ubuntu@aws1:~$ su
   Password:
   ```
3. Edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and comment out the the last HostKey statement or the one similar to the last one in the example below:

   ```
   vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

Then

```
    # HostKeys for protocol version 2
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
    #HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed00000_key
```

4. In same file, change the following to look like below:

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   #PasswordAuthentication no
   ```
5. Restart ssh

   ```
   service ssh restart
   ```
6. Log in as root with password from WinSCP

*I recommend creating a backup of the file sshd_config before editing and then revert back to original when done.

Comment: Service should be `sshd` so `service sshd restart`

Comment: @timothymarois  `sshd` for CentOS/ RedHat

Answer (score 1):

(Bug report?) This is my log on an instance of ec2, sometimes `sudo su` doesn't work. I have to log out and ssh again to have it working.

```
    [ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ su root
    Password:
    su: incorrect password
    [ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ exit
    logout
    Connection to ec2-50XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
    ssh -i automata.pem ec2-user@ecXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    whereis yum
    yum: /usr/bin/yum /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum /usr/share/man/man8/yum.8.gz
    [ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ sudo su
    [root@ip-XXXX ec2-user]#
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not even using Amazon AWS anymore. The real problem I had was I was using the wrong program, though.

Answer (score 1):

The file:

/etc/sudoers

has a line

Defaults    requiretty

Commenting this out probably will make the error go away.

I would first try to understand why something in your yum 
command does no longer have a tty.

Changing a security related file like 
/etc/sudoers is potentially quiet dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the sshd_config file to allow password based access 
And you need to add a password to your root user.
Simple just follow the steps-
     sudo passwd root
     sudo nano -w /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Uncomment/Add the following line `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Answer (score 0):

sudo su -l
Works the best for me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?